# Is possible to lay out plots and widgets on Bokeh with Bootstrap, Jiinja or similar?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, layout, jinja2, bokeh

I have an application with Bokeh library using it as a web server application. I have used tabs, widgetdboxes, gridplots to lay out all the elements. I have read [this](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html) on the documentation page, but I see many limitation laying out this way.

Is there an easy way to lay out all this elements with a template? Maybe using Jinja and Bootstrap? Is this possible?

An easy example would help me a lot.

### Update (July, 11th 2018)

Templates functionality was released with the [**0.13.0 Version of Bokeh**](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#standard-template)

> Below is a minimal example. Assuming that the application creates two
>   roots with names properties set:

```
p1 = figure(..., name="scatter")

p2 = figure(..., name="line")

curdoc().add_root(p1)
curdoc().add_root(p2)
```

> Then these roots can be referred to by name in the template, and
>   passed to the embed macro to place them wherever desired:

```
{% extends base %}

<!-- goes in head -->
{% block preamble %}
    <link href="app/static/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

<!-- goes in body -->
{% block contents %}
    <div> {{ embed(roots.scatter) }} </div>
    <div> {{ embed(roots.line) }} </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: well you can just output the elements and imbed them in your html. That should let you to have somewhat arbitary styling + layouts?

Comment: Do you mean by using bokeh as the application way? But I need to update the plots in a efficient way. And more than one plot should be linked because they share data. Is this possible with your proposal?

Comment: Are you asking about a "standalone" Bokeh document (i.e. no Bokeh server) or a Bokeh server application?

Comment: [This way](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#building-bokeh-applications).  I use the `bokeh serve` command. In this scenario, a Bokeh server uses the application code to create sessions and documents for all browsers that connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.12.5` templating of individual elements is only supported for standalone Bokeh documents (i.e. no Bokeh server) via the `components` function. Similar capability for elements of a Bokeh server application is still an open issue: [**#4986** Allow elements to be placed in server templates](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4986). Currently all elements (plots, widgets, etc.) must go in a Bokeh layout.